# List view in Customer Portal is not filtering; it is showing all records. What to do?

Tags: customer-portal, list-view

List view in Customer Portal is not filtering; it is showing all records. What to do?

Object type: Custom object
Profile: Clone of HVCP with read permission for the above object
Salesforce org: DEV

Comment: I found what was wrong and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the List View's filter criteria is a lookup field, then the profile should have `read permission` on that lookup field object.

Answer (score 3):

This might be happening because the fields used to filter are not available to the portal profile.

Comment: I was chasing my tail on this one a bit and didn't even think of it being this simple. Thanks for your answer, it fixed my issue!

Answer (score 1):

I know that in the portals (partner / customer), you will not directly see the records for a specific list view. You first need to select the listview and press go.
It's comparable to how list views work in the normal sfdc screens.
Also there, you first need to select the list view you want to see and hit go.

I believe there is a workaround for that to pre-select the selected listview by passing the listview that needs to be selected in the querystring.

You can know how the URL has to look when you change the selected listview then the URL in your browser address will change.